# Why can I monitor every pc's in my lan internet traffic from my computer?

Tags: networking, lan, network-traffic

I downloaded the software Capsa, and I wondered how come I can monitor the network traffic of all the devices in my LAN, and how come I can exactly see which website they went through and such. Why am I receiving traffic to my computer which is not intended for me, but for my router?

and another question is how can I stop that from happening? I don't want that someone would connect to my network and will have the option to see all the traffic of the other devices in it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you using hubs (instead of switches)?

Comment: @ysdx nope, i'm using a d-link dsl-6740u router...

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question, the following is written in the Colasoft Capsa FAQ:

"As a network analyzer, Capsa captures the traffic that the monitored network adapter delivers. In other words, if the monitored network adapter is used by a machine for network connection, then Capsa captures the traffic of that machine. If the monitored network adapter is connected to the port mirroring destination port of a managed switch and the destination port gets a copy of the whole network, then Capsa captures the traffic of the whole network. For information on how to deploy Capsa, please refer to http://www.colasoft.com/support/installation.php."

Regarding your second question, you might want to have a look at the guide here http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/answer/How-to-prevent-network-sniffing-and-eavesdropping

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my question is why is my network adapter receives a copy of my whole LAN network traffic? it's not supposed to be that way...